# object is not iterable and/or NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-views

Good evening. I'm new to Django and I'm playing around with the polls tutorial. I've added a new model "Section" which acts as a parent for a set of questions. That is working fine since it shows all the questions of a section on a html page.

What I'm trying to do now is displaying only one question per page, save the answer to the database and get the next question from the section. I tried this in a couple of different ways but nothing works. I hope you guys can guide me into the right direction.

```
URLS.PY
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex=r'^$', 
        view=UmfrageView.as_view(), 
        name='umfrage'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        view=DetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$',
        view=vote,
        name='vote'
    ),
 )
```

Trying to get the first question from a section:

```
VIEWS.PY
class DetailView(ListView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
    template_name = 'itbarometer/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        # Get question set via section slug
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug') or kwargs.get('slug')
        qs = Question.objects.filter(section__slug=slug).order_by('pub_date')
        try:
            return qs[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form
        return render(request, 'itbarometer/umfrage.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "Bitte eine Antwort auswählen.",})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:umfrage'))
```

HTML template detail.html:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>{{ question.question_text }}</legend>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
                    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
            <input class="button small" type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But I'll get

Exception Value:
'Question' object is not iterable

When deleting "for question in latest_question_list" in detail.html I'll get

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
R everse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'umfragen/(?P\d+)/$']

If I further delete "{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" from form action, I'll be getting an empty form layout. I suspect there is no data transfer.

What might be the problem?

Edit: models.py

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    section_description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.section_text

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.section_text)
        super(Section, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Question(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception Value: 'Question' object is not iterable

You are getting this because `get_queryset` in `DetailView` is returning a question object not a query set. if you change `return qs[0]` to `return qs` it will return a queryset instead of the first question in that list.

> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch Exception Value: R everse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'umfragen/(?P\d+)/$']

Now that the loop is removed, `question` is not defined. the call to the url tag is failing because its now missing an argument.

The layout is empty because it is referencing values in `question` but `question` was never set because that was being set in the loop.

If you do want to just deal with 1 question then remove the loop and change `context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'` to be `question` since that is what your template is referencing or consider subclassing [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) instead of `ListView` and implementing `get_object()` instead of `get_queryset()`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `ListView` (even if you call it a `DetailView` :)), which is built to display lists of objects.

The first step is to actually use [the generic `DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) that is shipped with Django, which is built to display single objects. Something like this:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class YourView(DetailView):
    model = Question
```

This will automatically assign the `Question` that matches the slug in the url to the template variable `question`. Remove the `{% for .. %}` and `{% endfor %}` and the `{% if ... %}` / `{% endif %}` pairs from your template and the single question should be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely look into generic.DetailView

Comment: The slug is a section for a set of questions, so I need a loop in DetailViews to get the next question after user hits save, right?

Comment: models.py has been added to question.